# Usage of Redis on Azure

Tags: azure, redis

I'm using Redis cache on the Azure.The Pricing tier of it as `Standard 2.5 GB`.So my question is, can you tell me how to see the current usage of memory on the cache ? In other words how much of more cache storage remaining for using in the future ? I have tried to find out it on the dash board. But unable to find out it.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cache-how-to-monitor/?

Comment: Oh...It's supper cool.Thanks a lot :) Would you like to put it as an answer   @GauravMantri ? Then I can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure redis cache diagnostics to get this information. Please refer to  [`How to monitor Azure Redis Cache - Available metrics and reporting intervals`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cache-how-to-monitor/#available-metrics-and-reporting-intervals) for more details. From this link, one of the available metrics is `Used Memory` which I believe you're looking for.

> **Used Memory**   The amount of cache memory used for key/value pairs in the
>   cache in MB during the specified reporting interval. This value maps
>   to used_memory from the Redis INFO command. This does not include
>   metadata or fragmentation.

I have not used REDIS Cache personally but if my memory serves me right, I read somewhere that you can find this information by executing REDIS commands through `REDIS Console` available in the portal as well. For more information about this, please see this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cache-configure/#redis-console.

Answer (score 0):

Run `INFO memory` command in Redis Console and look for `used_memory_human` parameter in output.